# jQuery modal dialog boxing not closing from iFrame

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery modal dialog with an iFrame in it that shows some content.  When a user selects an option in the iFrame, I make an Ajax call, and then I want to close my dialog, however it is not closing for me.

On my parent form I have a div tag:

```
div id="structureDialog" title="Add Structure"
```

I open my dialog when the user clicks an element on the parent:

```
// bind an onclick event onto tiles to display the modal dialogue window
$(".stationTile").bind('click', function () {
    var src = "<iframe src="myurl" />";
    var locationID = 1;
    $("#structureDialog").attr("locationID", locationID);
    $("#structureDialog").html(src);  //iframe
    $("#structureDialog").dialog({
        modal: true,               
    });    
});
```

In my iFrame I have the following:

```
$(".userOption").bind('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "/NewStructure.aspx/Build",   
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: buildSuccess
    });
});

function buildSuccess(res, dest) {
    $("body", window.parent.document).attr("style", "background-color:yellow;");
    $("#structureDialog", window.parent.document).attr("style", "background-color:red;");
    $("#structureDialog", window.parent.document).dialog('close');
}
```

In my function buildSuccess, I am able to successfully change my dialog box to red.  However, the close function will not close my dialog box.  From most examples I have seen so far, this code should work fine, so I'm stumped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment above, the solution is related to the instance of jquery being run.  When the dialog object is created, it is in the context of the jquery instance of the parent form.  In an iFrame, a second instance of jquery is created, and hence the dialog box is not in scope.

Calling `$("#structureDialog", window.parent.document).dialog('close');` searches the DOM of the parent using the local instance of jquery, and so since the dialog box was not initialized there, it cannot be closed there.

The solution is to reference the jquery instance of the parent by rearranging the terms as follows:

`parent.$("#structureDialog").dialog('close');`

This points the context to the parent first, and then uses the jquery instance of the parent to find the dialog box and close it.

Kudos to chrismarx1 on this post which pointed me to this solution: 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/trigger-from-iframe-to-parent-window

Comment: This is it! I've been searching for several hours now.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("#structureDialog", window.opener.document).dialog('close');
```

Comment: window.opener is null.  There is only one window used in this process, so I guess this makes sense.  The iFrame is in a div tag.  Also, I don't think the issue is with my selector, since the colour change happens successfully.  Any other ideas?

Comment: would jquery context have anything to do with this?  wondering if the dialog object is loaded into memory with the jquery instance of the parent, and this method above is accessing the dialog box object with a local-to-the-iframe instance of jquery?  But, from other examples I've seen, this should not be the case, so I"m not sure.

Comment: `window.opener.document` will use the jquery instance of the parent but if that would be the case the bg would not have changed also

Comment: I solved it... I was correct in that the problem was related to the jquery instance I was using.  I had to reference the parent instance of jquery using the following syntax:  `parent.$("#structureDialog").dialog('close');`

Comment: @GregoryJohnson thats nice you can post it as an answer and accept it so that in future it could help others

Comment: 3nigma: using $("selector", context) while searching the DOM from the context you suggest (ie: window.opener.document) still uses the local instance of jquery (the one in the iFrame), and not the instance of the parent.  just need to rearrange the terms a bit!  Thanks anyways for the efforts!